# Get HTML element in C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I would like to know how to retrieve an "a" element into a div.

I have an HTML like :

```
<div id="content">
<div class="divSearchForm">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr1">
                <td>
                    <img class="SearchImage">
                        List of systems
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" class="Result">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="test">K</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                            
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I would like to know how to get the "K" link.

For now, I have :

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("content").GetElementsByTagName("a");
```

But it looks like nothings happened.

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: add runas="server' and an id to the hyperlink and you can access the hyperlink normally

Comment: If you are trying to parse HTML I would recomend you using https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

Comment: Are you sure the document is already completely loaded when you are calling `GetElementById("content")` ?

Comment: @JonathanCamilleri, I cannot add an id to the hyperlink. I'm not the creator of the Website, i'm just using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are accessing the `Document` before it is completely loaded.

Add a listener to the `DocumentCompleted` event of the `WebBrowser` control

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
```

and try to access your Elements there:

```
protected void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement el = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("content").GetElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    String anchorText = el.InnerText; // will contain "K"
    String url = el.GetAttribute("href"); // will contain "test"
}
```